# to get the TOTAL of count

Tags: php, sql, count

```
SELECT * , COUNT(  `ftm_content_type` ) AS count,
       max(tot.totcount) as totcount
FROM ftm_points join
     (select count(*) as totcount from ftm_points) tot
GROUP BY ftm_content_type
```

I solve my problem with your help only

```
FTM_CONTENT_TYPE = 4 3 2 1
COUNT            = 3 2 3 2   =  TOTAL OF COUNT = 10(I need this result)
```

Comment: Which DBMS is this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only the total of count, then remove the `group by`:

```
SELECT COUNT(  `ftm_content_type` ) AS count
FROM ftm_points
```

If you need the total on the same line, then join it back in:

```
SELECT * ,
       COUNT(  `ftm_content_type` ) AS count,
       max(tot.totcount) as totcount
FROM ftm_points join
     (select count(*) as totcount from ftm_points) tot
GROUP BY ftm_content_type
```

And finally, if you want the total on a separate line, then use `rollup`:

```
SELECT * ,
       COUNT(  `ftm_content_type` ) AS count
FROM ftm_points 
GROUP BY ftm_content_type with rollup
```